# Am I using this dynamic array correctly?

Tags: c, file-io, dynamic-arrays

I need to create a dynamic array to hold strings that I am to read in from three files.  I am new to C and I don't really understand how to use pointers or allocate memory.  I would like to know if I am declaring my array correctly and if my `calloc()` calls are correct.  The format for the file I am to use is:

```
word1
word2
word3 (and so on)
```

I'm just to assume that the words from the files are no longer than 50 characters (including `\0`).

Eventually I will need to sort them, but I need to get them into an array before I try that.  Thanks for any help you may be able to give.

---

Here is what I have so far...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int countWords(FILE *f){
int count = 0;
char ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
    if (ch == '\n')
        count++;
}
return count;
}


int main(void){

int i;
int wordCount = 0;
int stringLen = 50;

FILE *inFile;

inFile = fopen("american0.txt", "r");
wordCount += countWords(inFile);
fclose(inFile);

inFile = fopen("american1.txt", "r");
wordCount += countWords(inFile);
fclose(inFile);

inFile = fopen("american2.txt", "r");
wordCount += countWords(inFile);
fclose(inFile);

printf("%d\n", wordCount);


char **wordList = (char **) calloc(wordCount, wordCount * sizeof(char));
for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
    wordList[i] = (char *) calloc(stringLen, stringLen * sizeof(char));
}

char ch;
int currentWord = 0;
int currentWordIndex = 0;
inFile = fopen("american0.txt", "r");
while ((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF){
    if (ch == '\n'){
        currentWord++;
        currentWordIndex = 0;
    }
    else
        wordList[currentWord][currentWordIndex] = ch;
}
inFile = fopen("american1.txt", "r");
while ((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF){
    if (ch == '\n'){
        currentWord++;
        currentWordIndex = 0;
    }
    else
        wordList[currentWord][currentWordIndex] = ch;
}
inFile = fopen("american2.txt", "r");
while ((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF){
    if (ch == '\n'){
        currentWord++;
        currentWordIndex = 0;
    }
    else
        wordList[currentWord][currentWordIndex] = ch;
}

printf("%s\n", wordList[57]);
for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
    free(wordList[i]);}

free(wordList);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a useful and clear question with source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't need the casts for the return value of `calloc`. The C language specifies that a value of type `void*` is compatible with any type of pointer to object. Adding the cast may hide the error of not including the header where `calloc` is declared. *In C++ the rules are different.*
- The function `calloc()` takes two arguments: the number of elements to allocate and the **size of each one**
- - In the first `calloc` you were trying to allocate `wordCount` elements of a strange size. I like to use the object itself as operand to the `sizeof` operator
- - In the 2nd `calloc` you were trying to allocate 50 elements of size 50 each. But you only want 1 element in each `wordCount`, right? Also `sizeof (char)` is, by definition, `1` so it doesn't buy you anything to multiply by it.

---

Try like this

```
char **wordList = calloc(wordCount, sizeof *wordlist);
for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
    wordList[i] = calloc(1, stringLen);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the `printf("%s\n", wordList[57]);` didn't give me a full string (just the letter 's' which is not in any of the files).  Is that the wrong way to try to print out, or is the way I added new data to the array wrong?

Comment: The way you add data is wrong: you need to increase `currentWordIndex` after every character. Also you should `fclose` the files once you're done with them.

Comment: Duh! Guess I missed that.  It works.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Michael: next assignment if you're so inclined :) the same way you wrote a function to count words, write a function to add the words in a opened file to the existing array (and get rid of code duplication -- triplication in your case -- for that functionality).

Answer (score 0):

In sizeof() you must use the type that you're allocating. A pointer to char is a different type than char itself and may (and under most circumstances does) have a different size. For example:

```
char **wordList = (char **) calloc(wordCount, sizeof(char*));
```

Also, you don't need to multiply the size of the pointer by the word count, calloc already does that for you. You could also do it this way:

```
char **wordList = (char **) malloc(wordCount * sizeof(char*));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using linked-list data structure.

Sample:
http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html

this suits better to your need.

Comment: What about "Eventually I will need to sort them"? Sorting a linked list is not for beginners :)

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation into a dynamiclt growing array isn't beginner either.

Comment: Right, but his array is of fixed size. Before allocating the array, he calculates the size ... and he frees the memory when done